# SPWebApplication.Sites not returning all Sites in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sitecollection

I have a timer job, which scans all sites and all webs. When looping through SPWebApplication.Sites, ALL BUT ONE Sites are listed.

this is the code:

```
  foreach (SPWebApplication app in service.WebApplications)
                {
                    foreach (SPSite site in app.Sites)
                    {
                        // site missing here   
                        foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                        { // stuff here  }
                    }
                }
```

All Sites are shown in the central administration. Any idea?

Comment: What is the one that is missing? Do you have the correct permissions? What about if you wrap this code in a `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` block?

Comment: I wrapped the inner part (after foreach web) into a RunWithElevatedPrivilegues This code is running in a JobDefinition. Should have the needed rights

Comment: PLease try to wrap the outer loop in this block. One possible cause is that the `app.Sites` enumeration has not enough privileges.

Comment: I will try that. But shoudn't the app.Sites be completely empty and not just missing one entry if that is the case?

Comment: It was something completely different. A Dispose-Isue in the Site-Object that was loaded before :)

Comment: Glad you find the solution. Please answer to your own question, in order to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a missing web.Dispose() in the inner loop which made the code crash just before the site-collection I was looking for.

As Dispose-Errors can not be caught in catch() it looks like the code was running "normal"